# How to reset Heading Counter in Asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm just learning asciidoc and using it for my first eBook. I can see that by adding my Preface as heading, it will take number 1 in chapter numbering. The first chapter will take number 2 and so on.
Ex:

```
== Preface

== First Chapter (Gets numberered as 2!)
```

This is not what I want. How can I reset the heading counter ? or use a workaround to start counting chapters from 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would deactivate the counter for your preface section:

```
:sectnums!:

== Preface

:sectnums:

== First Chapter
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Document types 'article' and 'book' have a 'preface' section:

```
[preface]
== Preface

:sectnums:
== First Chapter
```

See https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#section-styles